# how to apply audio filter using discord.py/ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot using discord.py and ffmpeg, I saw some js bot that can apply audio filters like [this](https://github.com/Tomato6966/Music-Bot-with-Filter/blob/main/Music/filter.js) , I really can't find anything similar using discord.py. It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The example you listed plays music from youtube (as most discord bots seem to be doing) with the ytdl library. Ytdl is the one that can interact with the ffmpeg to convert video to audio only (as can be seen in this documentation: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#post-processing-options).

This video implements something similar with ffmpeg: https://youtu.be/ml-5tXRmmFk?t=948 (added the approximate timestamp). So what you will need to do is to pass the filter flags, similarly to the JS example you linked.

If you don't want to use Ytdl you will need to interface with ffmpeg directly.

Answer (score -1):

Python FFMPEG library does not have a custom audio filter as you want but you can manipulate audio using various parameters and get the desired result. you can start from this page.
https://www.programcreek.com/python/?project_name=kkroening%2Fffmpeg-python